# Matplotlib labels: greek letter + italic + black font

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, visualization

I am trying to add a greek letter that is in black font and italic font at the same time. In this case is just bold. I am not sure if its possible the combination of the three.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.plot()
plt.xlabel(r'$ \it{\bf{\mu_{0}}}$ H  (mT)',fontsize = 12, fontweight='bold')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Matplotlib Documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/mathtext.html) may use a combination of `\mathbf` for italic bold math font and a definition of the font directly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'custom'
plt.rcParams['mathtext.bf'] = 'cm:italic:bold'

plt.xlabel(r'$\mathbf{\mu_{0}}$ H  (mT)', fontsize=12, fontweight='bold')
plt.show()
```

[image]